# Shared html in angular4 not working as expected?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am using a shared html for search in every page

search.component.html

```
   <form class="p-2" (ngSubmit)="searchHere(query)" #customersearch="ngForm">
  <div class="input-group custom-search-form float-right">
<input type="search" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default-sm" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
  </div>
 </form>
```

search component.ts

```
  @Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'search-items',
templateUrl: './search.component.html',
           })

    export class SearchComponent {

@Output() search = new EventEmitter<string>();
searchQuery:string;

searchHere(text?: string) {
    console.log(text)
    this.search.emit(text);
}

   }
```

i am using this in a customer component html like

```
 <search-items (search)="filter($event,'q')"></search-items>
```

when i click the search button, its working fine, but as the shared html is a form, when i click enter also search should work.

But when i click enter its calling filter function twice.
first its passing exact parameters, second time its passing an event type as parameter . how can i prevent it?

what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the same behavior as you got. i don't know why this issue is with name 'search' output event-emitter variable.please change this to any other name such as 'test' and do this in your

```
@Output() test= new EventEmitter<string>();

searchData() {
    this.test.emit(this.searchQuery);
}
```

and

```
<search-items (test)="filter($event)"></search-items>
```

This will work

Comment: still its calling the filter method twice. its not the answer for my question.

Comment: when i click enter button after clicking typing, its calling the method twice, first time $event has text. but second time its having an object of type event.

Comment: i know, it will work but as my shared html is a form, on click of enter the method is calling twice... still its happening.

Comment: it is not happening with me.it was only happening when i was using search variable.if you can share plunker of that.i can assist you on this issue

Comment: the angualr version i am using is angular 4

Comment: can we chat on this.i would like to take look into your issue

Comment: i have updated your plunker please do take look into this https://plnkr.co/edit/P0NjMMXNEGy5GD01R3n1?p=preview

Comment: just the term search. i need to look into that why this is issue